# Python. user input(1) string to list. User input (2) finds if there is the word in the first user input

Tags: python, python-3.x

*EDIT* The code is to show the position of the second input variable in the original sentence/list and it always returns 13 if you input to on the second input

Well my code needs to have a user input that is then converted into a list. I'm done with that part. I need help with the taking a second user input and then finding if that second user input is in the sentence that is provided from the first. My code I'm working on is below:

```
  sent = str(input("Sentence:"))
  sent.split()
  lkupwrd = str(input("What word do you want to look up?"))
  print (sent.index(lkupwrd))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `in`:

```
sent = input("Sentence:").split()
lkupwrd = str(input("What word do you want to look up?")).lower()

wordList = [word.lower() for word in sent]

if lkupwrd in wordList:
    print([i for i,j in enumerate(wordList) if j == lkupwrd])
```

You don't need to use `str` on `sent` because `input()` converts to `str` anyway.

More on: [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions), [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input),  [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower)

**Edit:**

This is a simple example of `enumerate()`:

```
myList = ["a","b","c","d","e"]

myListEnumerated = enumerate(myList)

print(list(myListEnumerated))
```

Output:

```
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c'), (3, 'd'), (4, 'e')]
```

As you can see, you can use `enumerate()` to find the index of each element. The `i` and `j` in the code above corresponds to the index and value of each element in the list.

Comment: Dude you are an absolute legend!

Comment: @AshleyThomas no problem :)

Comment: Dude would you please explain the code to me further I'm struggling to make sense of the i and j @Farhan.K

Comment: Yeah I kind of understand now, would it have to be i and j or could it be a and b etc.

Comment: It can be any valid variable name. Just like in a normal [`for`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_for_loop.htm) loop.

Comment: @AshleyThomas I edited my code to create a new list called `wordList` which contains the lowercase of everything in `sent`. This is to make sure it matches every word it finds regardless of case. As you can see, I used `word` as the variable this time instead of `i` or `j`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the output of the split function. To get a list of all occurrences of the lookupword you can use list comprehension. More on that can be found here: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

```
sent = str(input("Sentence:"))
sent = sent.split(' ')
lkupwrd = str(input("What word do you want to look up?"))
if lkupwrd in sent:
    print 'The word is in the sentence'
    print [i for i in range(len(sent)) if sent[i] == lkupwrd]
else:
    print 'The word is not in the sentence
```

Comment: .split() with no argument will split on spaces, but you need to actually use  the list it returns

Comment: Note - `split()` will by default split by whitespaces

Comment: Dude that's great thanks. But It has to show the position of the word in the list, how would I do that?

Comment: Credits go to dsh and Juxhin, I made a stupid mistake

Comment: But how would I show the positions of the word that is input, as in "To be or not to be" being input one, input two being "To" and then the output being 0 and 4

Comment: Edited answer; using list comprehension

Comment: Okay I don't have a clue haha

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> sent.split()
> ```

The `split()` method *returns* a list.  You need to assign the return value to a variable to use it.  The method does not modify the string object.

```
sent = sent.split()
```

However, I recommend using a different variable name for the str object and the list object.  I find it makes it easier to keep track of what the names mean and what operations are valid on them.

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you:

```
s = input("Sentence: ")
l = input("What word do you want to look up? ")
w = s.split()
if l in w:
    print "found @ {}".format(s.index(l))
else:
    print "not found"
```

**UPDATE**

If you want it case insensitive then change two lines to:

```
w = s.lower().split()
```

and

```
if l.lower() in w:
```

Comment: I don't understand why but it returns 13 when I input To be or not to be for the first input and to for the second

Comment: because that's the first index of "to" in the string.  "To" is not "to" if you want a case insensitive search you should say..

Answer (score 0):

There are some redundant steps in your code. See if the following works,

```
sentence = input("Sentence: ")
word = input("Word: ")
if word in sentence:
    print(sentence.index(word))
```

*No need to `split()` into a list. But the code will still work if you do it.*